# Update HTML page after jquery.click

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, asp.net, asp.net-mvc

I have an onclick function which basically just returns sorted data like following:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $(".feedbackClick").click(function () {
       $.post("/Analyze/GetSortedByFeedback")
              .done(function (data) {
                  var sellers = $('<table />').append(data).find('#tableSellers').html();
                  $('#tableSellers').html(sellers);
              });
       });
    });
});
```

And this is how the table looks like that I'm trying to update after the jquery post:

```
<table id="tableSellers" class="table table-striped jambo_table bulk_action">
    <thead>
       <tr class="headings">
            <th class="column-title"><h4><i class="fa fa-user" style="text-align:center"></i> <span>Username</span></h4> </th>
            <th class="column-title"> <h4><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-tasks salesClick" aria-hidden="true"></span></h4></th>
            <th class="column-title"><h4><i class="fa fa-star feedbackClick"></i></h4></th>

       </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
       @foreach (var item in ViewBag.rezultati)
       {
             <tr>
                 <td><a href="http://ebay.com/usr/@item.StoreName" target="_blank">@item.StoreName</a></td>
                 <td>
                    <b>
                    @item.SaleNumber
                    </b>
                 </td>
                 <td><b>@item.Feedback</b></td>                                                   
             </tr>
       }

    </tbody>
</table>
```

The click would basically just fetch the results and update the table in HTMl...

Can someone help me out?

Edit:

This current method doesn't works... I trigger the event but nothing happens... The code in the Action is called properly, but the results aren't displayed...

Edit 2:

This is the content of the data object after .done:

```
System.Collections.Generic.List`1[WebApplication2.Controllers.ResultItem]
```

Edit 3:

This is the action:

```
public List<ResultItem> GetSortedByFeedback()
{
    return lista.OrderByDescending(x => x.Feedback).ToList();
}
```

Edit4 this is the data after the Alexandru's post:

```
Array[100]
```

Now I can do:

```
data[0].Feedback
```

And this outputs in console:

```
61259
```

Comment: Are you sure about `$('<table />')` ?

Comment: No that's why I'm posting the question. I'm not sure how does the data object looks like, and what its content is ... :/

Comment: Please use `console.log(data)` in `done` function.

Comment: Your `.find('#tableSellers')` does not make sense - you cannot `.find()` something that has not been added to the DOM yet. All you need is `.done(function (data) { $(someElement).html(data); }` where `someElement` is an element that exists when the page is first rendered

Comment: Guys I've updated my question with the contents of the data object, can someone look into it?

Comment: @StephenMuecke How can this be applied to update my table with id "tableSellers"

Comment: Does `<table id="tableSellers" ..>` exist when the page is first rendered? And the method your calling is just return a collection of objects - it needs to return a partial view. Its unclear what you want to update in the DOM

Comment: @StephenMuecke yes

Comment: You must return data as JSON type.

Comment: Then your method needs to return a partial view based on the collection so that you can replace the existing `<table id="tableSellers" ..>` with the new `<table id="tableSellers" ..>` (or you return json, and read each object in the collection and generate new `<tr>` elements to append to the existing table

Comment: @StephenMuecke Can you post a reply in form of answer so that I can see what you mean and accept it if it's okay?

Comment: @AlexandruMihai Can you post an answer? :)

Comment: @User987 please post your action.

Comment: @AlexandruMihai I posted the action in my original question

Comment: @User987, You need to give a bit more information to understand what it is you trying to update. The view you have shown has a table based on `ViewBag.rezultati` - where does that come from. How is that related to `return lista...`? What are you actually updating in the table?

Comment: ViewBag.rezultati is actually the same list as the one GetSortedByFeedback (they are List<ResultItem>) , just the GetSortedByFeedback method returns the list as sorted one... :)

Comment: Then your method should be `public ActionResult  GetSortedByFeedback() {  ViewBag.rezultati = lista.OrderByDescending(x => x.Feedback).ToList(); return PartialView("xxx"); }` where `xxx` is the name of your partial view that generates that table (or you can return json, and manually generate the `<tr>` elements to add to the table)

Comment: Could you reply with answer so that I can see what do u mean exactly...

Do I just do RenderPartial("xxx") after the button click or ???

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please use this:

```
public JsonResult GetSortedByFeedback()
{
   var list=lista.OrderByDescending(x => x.Feedback).ToList();
   return Json(list);
}
```

If your method is `GET` please use this:

```
public JsonResult GetSortedByFeedback()
{
   var list=lista.OrderByDescending(x => x.Feedback).ToList();
   return Json(list,JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
}
```

Then please use this:

```
 .done(function (data) {
      $('#tableSellers tbody').empty();
      $.each(data,function(i,item){
           var tr='<tr><td><a href="http://ebay.com/usr/'+item.StoreName+'" target="_blank">'+item.StoreName+'</a></td><td><b>'+item.SaleNumber+'</b></td><td><b>'+item.Feedback+'</b></td></tr>';
           $('#tableSellers tbody').append(tr);//append the row
      });
  });
```

Comment: and the part where you convert the json to html in the ajax?

Comment: @AlexandruMihai how do I now fetch the data in .done and update the HTML ?

Comment: @User987 ,can you show your `data` after using my code ? `console.log(data)`.This helps me to updating your table.

Comment: @AlexandruMihai It looks like this :Array[100] , where now parameters are accessible like data[0].Feedback... and so on... How do I reconstruct the data now and update the html?

Comment: Notonly it works like a charm, it is beautiful to see it! Thanks @AlexandruMihai !!! You're the DUDE ! ! ! :)

Comment: @AlexandruMihai at least give me some credit for the js :))

Answer (score 1):

What you are trying to do is actually appending a JSON data to a HTML element which is of course will not work as expected.

Consider using a template engine like [jQuery Templates](https://github.com/BorisMoore/jquery-tmpl). You will be able to compile a HTML template and use it to render your data whenever you need. For example:

```
var markup = "<li><b>${Name}</b> (${ReleaseYear})</li>";

// Compile the markup as a named template
$.template( "movieTemplate", markup );

$.ajax({
  dataType: "jsonp",
  url: moviesServiceUrl,
  jsonp: "$callback",
  success: showMovies
});

// Within the callback, use .tmpl() to render the data.
function showMovies( data ) {
  // Render the template with the "movies" data and insert
  // the rendered HTML under the 'movieList' element
  $.tmpl( "movieTemplate", data )
    .appendTo( "#movieList" );
}
```

Answer (score 1):

TRy something like this:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $("body").on("click",".feedbackClick",function() {//delegate the click event
       $.get("/Analyze/GetSortedByFeedback",function(data) {
                  var sellers = $(data).find('#tableSellers').html();//find the table and take the html
                  $('#tableSellers').html(sellers);//append the html
              });
    });
});
```

Note: you need to return html (in your case) from the ajaxed page

from @Alexandru partial response you can do the following

```
public JsonResult GetSortedByFeedback()
{
   var list=lista.OrderByDescending(x => x.Feedback).ToList();
   return Json(list,JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
}
```

js:

```
 $(document).ready(function () {
        $("body").on("click",".feedbackClick",function() {//delegate the click event
           $.get("/Analyze/GetSortedByFeedback",function(data) {
                     $('#tableSellers tbody').empty();//empty the table body first
                     $.each(data,function(i,item){//loop each item from the json
                      $('#tableSellers tbody').append('<tr><td><a href="http://ebay.com/usr/'+item.StoreName+'" target="_blank">'+item.StoreName+'</a></td><td><b>'+item.SaleNumber+'</b></td><td><b>'+item.Feedback+'</b></td></tr>');//build and append the html
});
                  });
        });
    });
```

Comment: I'm getting an error: Syntax error, unrecognized expression: System.Collections.Generic.List`1[WebApplication2.Controllers.ResultItem]

Comment: this means you aren't returning html from the ajax, or your asp page has errors

Comment: For some reason this displays just 1 result instead of 100 initial ones before the click

Comment: @User987 sorry change html to append, updated my answer